# How can I sync my cdk project to deploy it from several computers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, lambda, deployment, aws-cdk

Hi I work in two computers: one running with MacOSX and one running with Ubuntu 23.04. My problem is that I have a CDK project where I build lambdas using Docker with the function:

```
lambda_function = aws_lambda.DockerImageFunction(
            scope=self,
            id=lambda_conf["id"],
            function_name=lambda_conf["function_name"],
            code=aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_image_asset(
                directory=lambda_conf["directory"],
            ),
            memory_size=lambda_conf["memory_size"],
            timeout=Duration.minutes(lambda_conf["timeout_minutes"]),
            role=lambda_role,
        )
```

I used to be able to deploy from both computers without problems, but I had a storage related issue and I had to clean the local Docker images in my Ubuntu pc, now when I try to deploy on it I got this exception:

```
The stack named prod-lambdas failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: "Source image account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/cdk-hnb659fds-container-assets-account_id-us-east-2:XXXXXXXX does not exist. Provide a valid source image. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: XXXXXXXXX)" (RequestToken: XXXXXXXX, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

How can I sync the cdk project in both computers so I do not run into this problem? I have been reading the cdk documentation but so far i cant figure it out the solution. Now I just can deploy from my MacOSx computer because in Ubuntu I got the mentioned error.

Comment: You need to pull the image down again to that computer, or rebuild it on that computer. It isn't really something the CDK is going to do fore you, it's just a `docker` command you need to run.

Comment: @MarkB i just thinking that, I tried to rebuild it but I got that error, so for example if a new person want to deploy the project, they have to manually download the docker images from aws? I did not have to do that before, that's where my confusion resides

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything. Did you remove any images from the CDK ECR repository?

Comment: @gshpychka No , i havent removed anything i just got that error after deleted my local docker images

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Try removing your cdk.out folder and doing `cdk deploy` again.

Comment: @gshpychka already tried that, but no luck

Comment: Create a minimal reproducible example that we can synth and deploy on our end.

Comment: A lot of bikeshedding here! Clearing `cdk.out` is a new one for sure. Have you verified that the ECR repository it's complaining about is actually there? I'd recommend following the issue I put in my answer as it seems to be the exact issue you're facing.

Comment: Clearing `cdk.out` would make CDK re-bundle all assets, so it could be helpful for getting through some bundling-related issues.